# Printer freezes when the paper go into the heater

Tags: printer, freeze, hp-laserjet, paper

I have `Hp 1018 laserjet`, It gets freeze when the paper go into the heater and the red light stays on `(not blinking)` until I remove the paper and restarts the printer again. I thought it may be because of the printer driver but it happens on the different PC too. What causes the problem.

Comment: Try cleaning the inside to see if something jams it? could be a start to see if there is a foreign obstacle in the way.

Comment: Obviously, the heater must be installed backwards. ;)

Comment: nope there is nothing jam in it , it was working fine till morning.
and obviously the heater is not installed backwards, if it was then it should not print any page till morning.

Comment: You may have a faulty fuser, or using the wrong kind of paper. What kind of paper are you using?

Comment: yes the problem is with the fuser..

Comment: To repeat: What kind of paper are you using? If you are using standard bond paper then you will need a new fuser. If you are using a different paper, that may be the cause of the problem, so please tell me what kind you are using.

Comment: I am using BLC papers.

Comment: Assuming you are using BLC photocopy paper, it means the fuser needs to be replaced - a you already discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the printer have been repaired ,

the problem was with the broken fuser assembly.

Replaces the fuser and the problem is solved.